# How to add a column to existing table but joining three tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hello I have a database

i am trying to add a column to the existing "SALE" table which calculates the payment required to the gallery calculated via sale_price * (gallery_sale_percent/100) and also payment to artwork creator calculated via sale_price*(1-0.2-(gallery_sale_percent/100))

i have tried this

```
Alter table sale add sale_gallery_commission number(9,2);
comment on column sale.sale_gallery_commission is 'Commission payment to Gallery';
update sale 
set sale_gallery_commission = ( select sale_price * gallery_sale_percent from 
                     sale s JOIN aw_display  d ON s.aw_display_id = d.aw_display_id 
                     JOIN gallery     g ON g.gallery_id = d.gallery_id );
```

but i get an error saying ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

how should i over come this??

Comment: Instead of trying to save a calculated value (which runs a high risk of being incorrectly modified) why not just calculate it at run-time, when needed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want a correlated subquery, not a `join`:

```
update sale s
    set sale_gallery_commission =
        (select sale_price * gallery_sale_percent
         from aw_display d join
              gallery g 
              on g.gallery_id = d.gallery_id
         where s.aw_display_id = d.aw_display_id 
        );
```

That said, it is not clear from your question if this will return more than one row as well.  If so, you would then probably want aggregation:

```
update sale s
    set sale_gallery_commission =
        (select sum(sale_price * gallery_sale_percent)
         from aw_display d join
              gallery g 
              on g.gallery_id = d.gallery_id
         where s.aw_display_id = d.aw_display_id 
        );
```